How do i compute P(theta|y > 0.100) in openbugs?
I need to use OpenBUGS to compute the posterior probability of the mean lifetime of a piece of equipment being greater than 100 hours.
Given that the data comes from an exponential distribution with parameter theta and that Theta has a prior distribution: Gamma(alpha = 45, beta = 5). Also there is a vector of data: Y = c(0.052, 0.105, 0.234, 0.031, 0.061, 0.243, 0.118, 0.173, 0.042, 0.007). The data corresponds to the lifetime of a piece of equipment measured in thousands of hours.
I do not know how to use BUGS and have very little time for me to learn the depths of it, as i work with R normally. If anyone can guide me through the GUI and code needed in order to get the result i need i would be very grateful.
Tried several iterations of the following:
model {
`#Likelihood`

for (i in 1:10) {
X\[i\] \~ dexp(theta)
}

# Prior

theta \~ dgamma(45, 5)

# Calcular la probabilidad de que theta \< 0.01

prob_theta_less_than_0.01 \<- step(0.01 - theta)
}
list(X = c(0.052, 0.105, 0.234, 0.031, 0.061, 0.243, 0.118, 0.173, 0.042, 0.007))\`

But the only output i got is a table of descriptive statistics signaling that the mean of prob_theta_less_than_0.01 is 0.

This may be a little too specialized for Stackoverflow; maybe try [stats.SE] instead, or maybe look for a forum specific to OpenBUGS.
